# Is there there a name to the practice of declaring one variable that is pointing to another variable?

Tags: html, css, variables, sass

I came across a unknown practice for me in SCSS a few days ago and I didn't want to go ahead and assume it was wrong without asking others first... here is an example:

```
$brand-color : red;
$var-used-only-twice : $first-var;
```

What value could this bring? i've asked other devs involved but nobody knows (or authored this) (this was seen in a large scale project), thanks in advance!

PD: this is not an opinion question, Im looking for a term if there is any.

Comment: This still really isn't appropriate for stack overflow, since it's not really a coding question. It's a naming convention - since there is no real right or wrong answer. I would think `assignment` is the word you're looking for, but that's my opinion. And also, asking about the _value it could bring_, is in fact opinion and depends on the use case. There are valid reasons to do that and there are invalid reasons to do so.

Comment: I've modified my variable names to convey a bit more meaning to my question, my point would be, is there a benefit to doing that if the 2nd variable is used only 2-3 times tops in the entire project (or any other similar scenario)?

Comment: Again, that's an opinionated question/answer. How do you know it will only be used 2-3 times - even if it is your code? IMO scalability should be one of the factors used in determining how you want to develop something. For what it's worth, I do exactly what's in your question for SCSS variables that have similar context (`a` and `button` tags) and then modify if needed - based on variants.